# Java-EE 7 Json Spec - Read/Write capability?

Tags: json, java-ee-7

Just started writing some code with the JSON reference library (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html), and run into a simple problem.  With a simple but "ugly" solution.

JsonObjects are 'immutable', despite being backed by a Map class, this means I shouldn't modify them.

I want to construct an object very dynamically, say, take an array and add an element to it, a full "read/write" model.

And yet the JsonObjectBuilder appears to implement a "write only" interface - you can put things in there but you can't ever read them (doesn't subclass map or anything?), so if you put an ArrayBuilder in there, you have to keep track of that if you later want to add to it (as there's no way of 'reading' the array builder back out and ...)

So there seams to be two interfaces, one is read only, and one is write only, and the only conversion possible is write-only to read-only, no way back, and no way to read/write a JSON structure.

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious...

The obvious "dirty" solution is of course to store the data in my own structure and then convert it to JSON builder at build time, tho this doesn't really help with the receiver of the JSON that needs to modify it and pass it on.  A two way interface between my object and its, or a converter that converts read only json's (recursively) back to builders and modifies it in the process...

What am I missing?  Why do I seem to have to build my own representation of the JSON and stream it in and out of RO / WO models?

(yes, i did try googling, nothing i came up with was helpful, which further confused me...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `JsonObjectBuilder` is used to write all the data you want finalized in a `JsonObject`. When you have built the `JsonObject`, you will most likely want to serialize him for transmission over HTTP by calling his [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonValue.html#toString%28%29) method. Then on the other end, if the receiver is a Java VM you would most likely want to use a `JsonReader` and begin reversing the process.

I think that the thing you "miss" could be a flaw in your design. Why would another entity need to mutate what has already been written to the JsonObjectBuilder? Wouldn't that mean that your first entity has failed his task?

The JSON API closely resembles how I build my own builder classes. They expose only setter methods, not getters. That is what the end product is built for. The state/value of fields has already been brought to the builder from an external source. Thus we could for most part safely assume that there is "no need" for getters. If we add getters too, they will pollute the API making it twice as big. My builders won't even allow consecutive calls to the setters, instead they throw an `IllegalStateException` if someone tries to put in a value into a field that has already been written to. Trying our utmost best to keep objects immutable is a golden rule for thread safety. Simply put it, you need no synchronization or other concurrency mechanisms for immutable objects. Builders is often a chief design pattern to achieve immutability.

Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't the JSON object you're trying to build already backed by a domain model? Say you have a Person class and you want to stringify him using JSON syntax? Well in that case, you shouldn't need to build the JSON string until he's ready to be dispatched somewhere [remotely]. Or as you're kind of saying yourself:

> The obvious "dirty" solution is of course to store the data in my own
>   structure and then convert it to JSON builder at build time [..].

That is no dirty solution at all. The receiver receives a `String` and need to parse that String into his own domain model, do whatever he like to with that object, and perhaps stringify the object again before dispatching him somewhere else to a third receiver.

If the receiver resides in the same Java VM, then why would you need to use JSON at all?

I feel I might have not been of much help to you, but if so, please update your post and describe your problem a little bit more detailed and I'll get back to you with my thoughts on that.

Comment: Hi, yup, afraid not much use.  I'm planning to build a system that is essentially a large chain of components, all java for now, and mostly "local", but eventually remote tasks in other languages could join the chain... JSON seemed a good 'message format', flexible etc... Aside from being able to natively just work on JSON objects dynamically the big gotcha at the end of the day seems to be this:  
  
If I receive a JSON message, and my job is just to add an element to somewhere and then pass on the JSON message, why am I forced to deconstruct the entire data structure and rebuild?

Comment: Thanks for replying tho, no-one else even managed to say "yup, no can do!".  I've used JSON in another language (Second Life's LSL) where native data structures are terribly bad and actually just storing "state" in the JSON as it passes around parts of code works really well, in a system where you're already passing it between lots of code, systems and languages, why deserialise/serialise twice?  "serialised form" -> JSON object form -> my data structure -> JSON Builder -> Serialised form.  I can only modify at "my data structure".  Seems deliberately inefficient.

Comment: (Particularly, if i have to write my own code to 'deserialise/decode' the JSONObjects into my data class, and then re-encode them into a JSONBuilder, for the sole purpose of using its serialisation/deserialisation... and yet its internal data structure is EVERYTHING i need, the ONLY reason to build a converter interface like that is because I'm forced to... nothing about my design benefits from this step, i achive the same goal indirectly anyway so the end goal cant be "impossibly wrong"... so why is this so forced)

Comment: Oh, and concurrency concerns I'm already dealing with.  Each message has a very singular pipeline through the system, and by its self is never processed in parallel, just the serial nature of the chain of processes.  Should it split into multiple processes the message is cloned (and not just for concurrency reasons, this makes sense from the design).  Concurrency issues happen much later on in my design and I have no concern about this. Me sadly replacing the whole thing with Map<String,String> instead still has those concerns, they're not specific to JSON.

Comment: TLDR from the above, this all seems absolutely crazy when all you want is a method that receives a JSON from somewhere remotely, does some processing, adds a value to the JSON and re-transmits it.  Nothing about JSON its self means this can't be done as simply as `json.set(["key"],"value"); return json`, but thanks to the limitation it becomes hundreds of lines of code to achive the /exact same thing/ (particularly once its serialised and loses its memory reference)

Comment: (spamming now), actually it occurs to me that the most code and probably time efficient method to modify the JSON is to serialise it to a string and mess around with that directly.  If that's the solution I feel that's a big design failure in the API.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply and I still haven't read through all your comments. It feels great to know there are other passionate programmers out there who wants to find "the truth" and write efficient code. For now, if you think that my answer was useful, consider casting an upvote and perhaps even marking the answer as approved.

Comment: @iain: Are you maybe just looking for something convenient like "new ObjectMapper().witeValueAsJson(whateverObject)" from the org.codehaus.jackson.map Package?